# Subset dataframe based on indicator variables

Tags: r

Using R, how can one subset a dataframe that has indicator variables, based on a vector of columns?

```
# Dataframe with 3 indicator variables - a, b, and c
df = data.frame(a = c(1, 0), b = c(1, 1), c = c(0, 1))

subset.iv = function (df, cols) {
    # ???
}

# Subset rows that match a or c (i.e. a=1 or c=1):
subset.iv(df, c('a', 'c'))

# Subset rows that match b (i.e. b=1):
subset.iv(df, c('b'))
```

I know how to subset a dataframe based on a known/static condition (e.g. `df[df$a == 1 | df$b == 1,]`).

But in this case the problem is that I can't write the condition expression since I don't know the number of columns to check for, or the columns themselves.

Also, `subset` doesn't allow passing a custom function where I might be able to parse the vector and check for columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your indicators are positive for yes and zero for no then something like this might work

```
subset.iv = function (df, cols) {
  df[rowSums(df[cols])>0, ]
  }
```

giving

```
> subset.iv(df, c('a', 'c'))
  a b c
1 1 1 0
2 0 1 1
> subset.iv(df, c('b'))
  a b c
1 1 1 0
2 0 1 1
> subset.iv(df, c('c'))
  a b c
2 0 1 1
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Your solution is about 44 times faster than mine (with `matchIV`), for the dataset I was working on.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found another way to think about it, and came up with this solution. Not sure it's very efficient, but would welcome feedback...

```
matchIV = function(row) {
  for(cn in cols){
    if(row[[cn]] == 1) {
      return(TRUE)
    }
  }
  return(FALSE)
}

sel <- apply(df,1,matchIV)

df2 = df[sel,]
```